# Why does updating one QSlider set the value of another QSlider?

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, macos-monterey, qslider

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication  app(argc, argv);
    {
        auto w = new QWidget();
        
        QSlider *verticalSlider;
        QSlider *verticalSlider_2;
        
        verticalSlider = new QSlider(w);
        verticalSlider->setGeometry(QRect(70, 70, 22, 160));
        verticalSlider->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
        verticalSlider_2 = new QSlider(w);
        verticalSlider_2->setGeometry(QRect(140, 70, 22, 160));
        verticalSlider_2->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
        
        w->show();
    }
    
    return app.exec();
}
```

When I slide `verticalSlider` to a different value, then switch focus to a different window, `verticalSlider_2` gets set to the value of `verticalSlider`.

If I switch the orientation of `verticalSlider_2` to `Qt::Horizontal`, the sliders are able to move independently.

[image: Demonstration GIF]

- Why is the second slider being set to the same position as the first?
- What do I need to do so the sliders of the same orientation can move independently?

---

I'm using:

- MacOS 12.6 (Monterey)
- Qt 5.15.2

Comment: Probably the same problem here: [Qt QSlider odd behaviour when changing widget with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155810/qt-qslider-odd-behaviour-when-changing-widget-with). I cannot reproduce this on KDE Neon with Qt6 (5.2/5.0/4.3/3.2/2.4). You should mention the OS and Qt version you're using in your question.

Comment: Another post with a workaround (duplicate?): [QSlider in QT misbehaves in new MacOS Monterey (v12.0.1) . Any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890284/qslider-in-qt-misbehaves-in-new-macos-monterey-v12-0-1-any-workaround), and a bug report [QTBUG-98093: QSlider is broken in MacOS Monterey](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-98093).

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub Thanks for the suggestions. Added OS and QT version to the question.